# What is the difference between parsys component and responsive layout in AEM

Tags: java, components, adobe, aem

I've realised that I can include **parsys** component to a page to allow content authors to add components on that place. Now when I was reading about responsive layout (**responsivegrid**) component, it seems like it's doing the same?

I am interested in the difference, what should be used and in which case.
There's a lot more in AEM documentation about Responsive layout, then about parsys so if someone can explain me this in a simple way or with some examples, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responsive behaviour across different view ports is the main difference between a parsys and layout container.

With parsys, you drag and drop components and the position of these components remains the same in all viewports.
Take for example a tile component which is positioned horizontally for desktop viewports and you want it stacked vertically as the viewport decreases, with just the paragraph system, you would require CSS changes or a responsive framework like bootstrap to achieve this.

[image]

With layout container, you get responsive features OOTB where you can define the position of the component for different viewports in Layout mode.

[image]

I've just illustrated a very simple example here, the component comes loaded with lots of responsive features.

The sample content we.retail project has examples of layout container which you can use as ref, also [Adobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/responsive-layout.html) on this topic is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Looks Responsive Layout is more powerful one. Can I always prefer Responsive Layout over parsys? What would be the case that parsys is a better solution than Responsive Layout?